# Strange periodical CPU consumption

Tags: windows-8, cpu

On my Windows 8.1 notebook (a Dell Latitude) I periodically (every about two weeks) notice this strange behaviour:

- CPU (i5) runs almost always at 100% for a couple of hours
- System sounds play very bad
- If I monitor the situation with Process Hacker, I see **every** process consuming about 10 times the CPU it consumes normally totalizing the 100%; e.g. if when I normally use a process it consumes 2% of CPU, when this happens it consumes 20%. Explorer had peaks of 60%...
- When this situation appears, explorer or livecomm sometimes hang (they don't respond within the expected time) and the system restarts them
- When I hit a key on the keyboard it takes a couple of seconds to display on the screen

It feels to me that the CPU is running 10 times slower.

I tried:

- disabling Windows Defender: it seems to be not relevant
- Rebooting: nothing changes
- Stopping many services: irrelevant
- Running with or without the AC adapter connected: irrelevant

Just now, it stopped behaving like this, allowing me to write this SU question.

Seems similar to this SU question [Windows 100% CPU with no apparent reason](https://superuser.com/questions/956386/windows-100-cpu-with-no-apparent-reason).
Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you got any intense scheduled tasks running like AV or system backups?

Comment: Initially I thought it was as you say, but in that case I expect to see those processes in the Task Manager, but no "strange" process appears there: only the usual processes, but all with high CPU consumption.
Are there any "hidden" process I can search for? Viruses, for example, can hide themselves from the Task Manager?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs generated at about the same time?

Comment: In the Event Viewer > Application Log, the only things I can see are the hangs of explorer.exe and LiveComm.exe.

Comment: And in the System log?

Comment: Do you use [Windows Mail](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/3994-73-livecomm-constantly-downloading-something) as your email client?

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the issue and share it: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD